# Trying to insert data for models that has polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I'm having a problem in trying to insert data into the db which has complex form involving two  models and I searched every post on Stackoverflow to find the best possible answer, but I couldn't get anywhere near close in getting it right.

In my Models

```
class ClientIndividual < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :client_assignment, :as => :clientassignmentable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_assignment
end

class ClientAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :clientassignmentable, :polymorphic => true

end
```

In my ClientIndividual Controller

```
class ClientIndividualsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_client_individual, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @client_individual = ClientIndividual.new

  end

  def create
   @client_individual = ClientIndividual.new(client_individual_params)

   respond_to do |format|
      if @client_individual.save
        format.html { redirect_to @client_individual, notice: 'Client individual was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @client_individual }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @client_individual.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_client_individual
      @client_individual = ClientIndividual.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def client_individual_params
      params.require(:client_individual).permit(:title, :first_name, :middle_name, 
:last_name, :date_of_birth, :work_phone, :home_phone, :mobile_phone, :email_address, 
:preferred_contact_type, :residential_address, :residential_suburb, :residential_state, 
:residential_postcode, :same_as_residential, :postal_address, :postal_suburb, 
:postal_state, :postal_postcode, :emergency_contact_person, :emergency_phone_no, 
:industry_type, :has_referral, :notes, clientassignmentable_attributes: 
[:assignment_types_id, :employees_id, :start_date, :manager_id, :client_type] )
    end
end
```

In my Client_Individual#new view

```
<%= form_for(@client_individual) do |f| %>
   <div class="add_data_section">

     <%= f.fields_for (:clientassignmentable) do |client_assignment_form| %>
      ........
      ........
      <div class="row_container">
        <div class="field 1" style="width: 409px;">
          <%=client_assignment_form.label :assignment_types_id, "Assignment Type*"%>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <label>
             <%= select('client_individual[clientassignmentable]', 'assignment_types_id',  AssignmentType.all.collect {|assignment_type| [assignment_type.name, assignment_type.id ] }, {prompt: 'Select Assignment Type'}, :style =>"width: 264px;")%>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row_container">
         <div class="field " style="width: 409px;">
           <%=client_assignment_form.label :start_date, "Assignment Start Date"%>
         </div>
         <div class="inputfield">
            <%=client_assignment_form.text_field :start_date, :class=>'assignmentdatepicker', :style=>'width: 260px;'%>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row_container">
         <div class="field " style="width: 409px;">
           <%=client_assignment_form.label :manager_id, "Manager Appointed*"%>
         </div>
         <div class="dropdown">
           <label>
              <%= select('client_individual[clientassignmentable]', 'manager_id',  Employee.all.select{ |manager| manager.staff_rank_id == 2}.collect{|employee| [employee.first_name + " " + employee.last_name, employee.id ] }, {prompt: 'Select ManagerList'}, :style =>"width: 264px;")%>
           </label>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row_container">
         <div class="field 1" style="width: 409px;">
           <%=client_assignment_form.label :employees_id, "Staff Appointed*"%>
         </div>
         <div class="dropdown">
           <label>
               <%= select('client_individual[clientassignmentable', 'employees_id',  Employee.all.select{ |employee| employee.user_id == current_user_id}.collect{|employee| [employee.first_name + " " + employee.last_name, employee.id ] }, {prompt: 'Select CurrentUser'}, :style =>"width: 264px;")%>
           </label>
         </div>
       </div>
     <%=client_assignment_form.hidden_field :client_type%>
   <% end %>
......
<% end %>
```

So what I have is that I got a ClientIndividual Model that has one ClientAssignment Model. So the ClientAssignment Model has ClientIndividual FK thus upon creating a new ClientIndividual data, I would expect a new ClientAssignment data that gets generated on the form. Thus in my controller, I declare my strong params like so

```
clientassignmentable_attributes: [:assignment_types_id, :employees_id, :start_date, :manager_id, :client_type]
```

But I click to save the new data, nothing's inserted into the db...

Then I check my development.log and it said the following.

```
Started POST "/client_individuals" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-30 19:58:52 +1100
Processing by ClientIndividualsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"0Z+BJcjQE7oa+uzdo/2sKRPiV01EQDXfedMkLE7pTjg=", "groups"=>{"id"=>"1"},     "client_individual"=>{"clientassignmentable"=>{"assignment_types_id"=>"1",     "start_date"=>"03/31/2014", "manager_id"=>"13", "employees_id"=>"25", "client_type"=>""},     "title"=>"t", "first_name"=>"t", "middle_name"=>"t", "last_name"=>"t", "date_of_birth"=>"",     "work_phone"=>"", "home_phone"=>"", "mobile_phone"=>"",     "email_address"=>"admin@example.com", "residential_address"=>"t", "residential_suburb"=>"t",     "residential_state"=>"t", "residential_postcode"=>"t", "same_as_residential"=>"0",     "postal_address"=>"t", "postal_suburb"=>"t", "postal_postcode"=>"t",     "emergency_contact_person"=>"", "emergency_phone_no"=>"22223", "industry_type"=>"",     "notes"=>""}, "CREATE"=>"Create Client"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1     ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
Unpermitted parameters: clientassignmentable
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m
```

I keep getting this unpermitted parameters: clientassignmentable. But I've already whitelisted in the my controller as one of the strong params so why is it complaining???

Surely this couldn't be hard to figure out if you know what's the correct association laid out in front of you already?

What else could I be missing?!?!  I've been on this for the whole day, looking very confused....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write

```
fields_for :client_assignment
```

and change this accordingly everywhere else you use `:clientassignmentable`

further reading:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

To solve the problem with fields not rendering in new form, in controller you need to do

```
@client_individual.build_client_assignment
```

Comment: Don't you mean fields_for :client_assignment, not form_for :client_assignment?  Cause I need the main form to save the new Client Individual form.  However, later on, I found the solution from another post that suggested I should do something like this

fields_for :client_assignment, ClientAssignment.new do |client_assignment_form|

Cause if I only do fields_for :client_assignment only, the nested attributes will not get rendered.  Because it think the ClientAssignment's a nil class upon creating a ClientIndividual.

Comment: @awongCM great catch, fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think where I did go wrong with this.....

It's so embarrassing after reading the basics of setting up polymorphic associations, I realised my polymorphic association was completely utterly wrong!!

As a consequence of that, I wasted almost 2 days of trying to save the form's data when clearly my initial steps of database design was utterly wrong!  What a complete utter waste!!!

ARRRGGGH!!!!!

Now I need to go back to the drawing board and find what how to revert it!!!

Comment: You wasted some time, but hopefully you also learned something. It's good to take a look at docs frequently, will save you some headaches.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Indeed I should.  I need to get into the habit of doing this before I get cracking with the code.  I should practice the habits of reading/practising the basics before I do any actual code.  Otherwise I'm going to run into the same problem again in the future and it surely doesn't look good...